# phpMyAdmin incorrect results count

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Stumbled across potentially a bug(?) within phpMyAdmin, although it's more likely to maybe be my misunderstanding of MySQL, so was hoping someone could shed some light on this behaviour.

Using the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mlfsql_test` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `frequency_length` smallint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
    `frequency_units` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `next_delivery_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_created_delivery_date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `mlfsql_test` 
(`id`, `frequency_length`, `frequency_units`, `next_delivery_date`, `last_created_delivery_date`) VALUES
(1, 2, 'week', '2014-06-25', NULL),
(2, 3, 'day', '2014-06-27', NULL),
(3, 1, 'week', '2014-08-08', NULL),
(4, 2, 'day', NULL, '2014-06-26');
```

I want to determine rows with an upcoming delivery, based on their currently set delivery date, or their last delivery date with the frequency taken into consideration.

Came up with the following query which works fine:

```
    SELECT *, IF (next_delivery_date IS NOT NULL, next_delivery_date,
        CASE frequency_units
            WHEN 'day' THEN DATE_ADD(last_created_delivery_date, INTERVAL frequency_length DAY)
            WHEN 'week' THEN DATE_ADD(last_created_delivery_date, INTERVAL frequency_length WEEK)
            WHEN 'month' THEN DATE_ADD(last_created_delivery_date, INTERVAL frequency_length MONTH)
        END)
    AS next_order_due_date
    FROM mlfsql_test
    HAVING next_order_due_date IS NULL OR (next_order_due_date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

With the data currently in the table, I am expecting it to return 3 rows, but phpMyAdmin states there are a total of 4 rows of results, although it only displays 3...

[image: picture 1]

I've found that if I add a WHERE clause to my query such as `WHERE 1`, it'll return the 3 rows and also state that there is a total of 3.

[image]

Why does it give an incorrect number of returned rows without the `WHERE` clause? I'm assuming without one phpMyAdmin assumes that all rows will match, however only returns those that actually did, so the count is wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** phpMyAdmin Version 4.2.0

Comment: Do you meanr For same query it will display different row. Am i right?

Comment: The first query will return a total of 4 rows, although it only displays 3. Adding a `WHERE` will return a total of 3 rows, and displays 3. Interested as to why it would make a difference, why is the first total rows wrong, or if it's me that has got something wrong.

Comment: I am tested your given query which will return always 3 records and display 3 rows where your problem?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4131e1/1

Comment: @Sadikhasan test it in phpMyAdmin, not a sqlfiddle. That's where the issue is.

Comment: @MLeaFevre I checked in phpMyAdmin but not any issue as you mention above.

Comment: I confirm it is showing wrong number of rows in current development version. It would be great if you can specify which version you are using.

Comment: @ChirayuChiripal Currently using `5.5.37-0ubuntu0.13.10.1`

Comment: @MLeFevre I mean which phpMyAdmin version.

Comment: @ChirayuChiripal oops sorry, `Version 4.2.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in phpMyAdmin v4.2.x. I have opened a bug ticket (see [Bug #4473](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4473/)). I have also proposed a fix for this bug to them (see [PR #1253](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/pull/1253)). You can also apply this [patch](https://github.com/D-storm/phpmyadmin/commit/96751a4756cb18bc0a04484be413dd5173ea9fd8.patch) to fix it in v4.2.4. This is most likely to be fixed in upcoming bugfix release i.e. v4.2.5.

**Edit 1:** My patch was accepted and this issue is fixed in v4.2.5 (upcoming minor release).

Comment: Nice one, glad to see it wasn't my mistake for once!